# Want to call api after every 5 second in react native axios api call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, react-hooks, axios

here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {

  var form = new FormData();

  form.append("user_id", user_id);

 axios.post('http://192.168.29.194/expense_calculator/index.php/API/get_all_transaction',form).then

((response) => {

          console.log('sss',response.data.data);

          if(response.data.data){

            setData(response.data.data);

          }

        });

      },[]);
```

Comment: why dont you use sockets?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function postForm(){
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("user_id", user_id);
  axios.post('http://192.168.29.194/expense_calculator/index.php/API/get_all_transaction',form)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('sss',response.data.data);
      if(response.data.data){
        setData(response.data.data);
      }
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => postForm, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(timer);
},[]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval